# Visualization of a set of data with a shape $ m \times n \times 3 $ with the last dimension interpreted as a color scale

Tags: plotting, color, visualization

Actually, if the data is shaped as $ m \times n \times 2 $, functions like `ListLinePlot` just do the job. But now I want to add colors to the curves according to each 3rd data. But it has stuck me. Any ideas?

---

A simpler version of the question should be this: Suppose I have an $ n \times 3 $ shaped data (below is not code but just what shows the spirit, and generation of test data is not difficult to implement by, say, `RandomReal` or `RandomInteger`):

```
data = {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, ..., {xn, yn, zn}};
```

Using `Graphics3D[Line[data]]` or `ListPointPlot3D[data]` can visualize it. But sometimes one has to work in just 2D, then how to encode the information carried by `zi` on the 2D curve sampled out by `{xi, yi}`?

Comment: It is unclear to me what type of data you want to visualize and what the result should be. Furthermore, I fail to see how `ListLinePlot` can handle $m \times n \times 2$ data strucutre.

Comment: @Natas Thx for responding. Something like `ListLinePlot[RandomReal[1, {3, 10, 2}]]` answers your 2nd point. For the 1st one, please see the 4th example of *Basic Examples* on [this page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html), except that there it is `Plot` that is in use for the case that the function expression of the curve is known.

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear[colorDataListLinePlot]
Options[colorDataListLinePlot] = {
    "ColorScheme" -> "NeonColors"
    }~Join~Options[ListLinePlot];
colorDataListLinePlot[datum_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{
   data = datum[[All, {1, 2}]], 
   colorfun = 
    Function[{x}, InterpolatingPolynomial[datum[[All, {1, 3}]], x]]
   }, ListLinePlot[data,
   ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y}, 
     ColorData[OptionValue["ColorScheme"]][colorfun[x]]],
   FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ListLinePlot]]
   ]
  ]
```

The problem is that `ColorFunction` expects a continuous function and needs to be defined everywhere. I used `InterpolatingPolynomial` which does not give so nice results, but this might be because of the random nature of the data.

```
(*3 x 10 x 3 data structure with the "x"-component increasing*)
data = Table[{i, RandomReal[{-1, 1}], i}, {3}, {i, 10}];
Show@Table[
  colorDataListLinePlot[datum, "ColorScheme" -> "Rainbow", 
   PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, {-1, 1}}], {datum, data}]
```

[image: Various plots with random data]

Answer (score 3):

`VertexColors`:

```
data = Table[{x, Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}];
{x, y, z} = Transpose[data];

Graphics[{
  Thick,
  Line[Transpose[{x, y}], VertexColors -> Hue /@ z]
  }]
```

[image]